# Move tabs to top when scrolling

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating mobile application using ionic framework.There are 3 tabs in my app and I need a feature like in whatsapp, as shown in this pictures.

**1.Initial whatzapp home page**

[image]

**2.Moving tabs to top when scrolling**

[image]

This is the view code that I'm using:

**tabs.html**

```
  <ion-view title="myApp">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
            <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
        </ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive ">
            <ion-tab title="Home" href="#/tab/home">
                <ion-nav-view name="contact-home"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab title="Contact" href="#/tab/contact">
                <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab title="About" icon="" href="#/tab/about">
                <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
    </ion-view>
```

How to  move tabs to top when scrolling, as does whatsapp?

Comment: use this http://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/ChIEt

Comment: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/hIzFp or http://codepen.io/kaililleby/pen/HALnJ

Answer (score 0):

Mushin,

If you want to make it 'stick' to the top, you will need to set the css of the top div to `position:fixed`.

```
.tabs-positive { 
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
 }
```

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) is an example.

If you want that nice scroll out effect of the topmost bar, with the Calls/chats/contacts sticking to the top after topmost bar is hidden then you will pb need to do it via scroll listeners

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('top');`

To fix the tabs on top.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? As in where to run that code? Otherwise this answer would be flagged as low quality. Thanks

Comment: The above code will fix the ion tabs to top but below the header. You need to do dom manipulation when scrolling inorder to fix the tabs on top.